# ocaml's compiler's documentation

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml

Did anyone have a try to build the ocamldoc's documentation for ocaml's compiler?

Reading the source tree recently, I can get the general idea how it works, but it would be
great if there's some documentation since I am afraid I may miss something. Either English or
French will be ok for me

Many thanks

Comment: (For the record, tell us if you get answers from here http://www.1771.in/ocamls-compilers-documentation-2.html )

Comment: I put the documentaion here (now you can read the compiler in your ipad) http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~hongboz/hongbo_zhang_files/typing.docdir/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~hongboz/hongbo_zhang_files/typing.docdir/index.html
The code is kept, so you can read the source tree of the compiler when you're traveling

Answer (score 0):

The only ocamldoc comments (they start with `(**` and obey some formatting) I see in the source tree are in ocamlbuild/, ocamldoc/ and stdlib/.

In particuler, no such comments in asmcomp/, asmrun/, bytecomp/, parsing/...

So, depending on which part of the ocaml compiler you're interested in, the ocamldoc documentation might not exist.

This seems interesting: http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/ocaml-internals/ but is intended for beginners, which you probably aren't anymore.

Comment: Yes. My documentation means html output with code kept. I managed to build the documentation, but ocamldoc prefers .mli to .ml which makes --keep-code not very useful. Once I am done, I will be happy to share